# OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud is not being shown while it's boundaries are obeyed

Tags: android, openstreetmap

I am using

```
feature.popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("pop",
feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
new OpenLayers.Size(80,80),
'<div style="overflow: auto;"><small><small><b>'+feature.attributes.description+'</b><br>Tap anywhere to close</small></small></div>',
null,
false,
function() 
{                       
  controls['selector'].unselectAll();  
}
);
```

to show a framedCloud Popup on a map when the user taps on an icon on the map.

This works well on every desktop browser but the first time I used my android phone to view it, the popup did not show. Just the content

```
<div style="overflow: auto;"><small><small><b>'+feature.attributes.description+'</b><br>Tap anywhere to close</small></small></div>
```

was shown floating "in the air" with no white background. It was within the framedCloud Popup's borders. It seemed as if the graphics of the framedCloud Popup were not being received but everything else was.

What could be the cause?

Answer (score 0):

The background is actually an image that's relative to the OpenLayers.js file:
  img/cloud-popup-relative.png

I'm guessing you're putting into a webview.  Make sure you have this directory of images from OpenLayers on your device...